# A criterion to be a rigid tensor category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra, algebraic-groups, representation-of-algebras

Let $C$ be a $k$-linear abelian category in the sense of [Deligne & Milne's notes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjgm7Gz1rDyAhVNCt4KHe2vAcAQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jmilne.org%2Fmath%2Fxnotes%2Ftc2018.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0f_qfPr_Il-pkw4z46FlJc), in which $k$ is a field. Proposition 1.20 in the book states that give such a category together with an exact faithful functor $F: C \to \mathrm{Vect}_k$ (the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over $k$), then $C$ itself is a rigid abelian tensor category.

The authors did not write a full proof but just assert that it can be proved directly without referring to the next section in which they prove $C$ is isomorphic to the category $\mathrm{Rep}_k(G)$ of finite dimensional representations of a $k$-group scheme $G$. In addition, the note that the condition:

> if $F(L)$ has dimension $1$, then there exists an object $L \otimes L^{-1} = U$.

is sufficient to show that $C$ is rigid. I don't even understand why should we need this condition. I tried to demonstrate the existence of the dual (hence, the internal hom) $X^{\vee}$ for every object $X$ but it seems that the condition of $F$ being only faithful is not strong enough. Any suggestion on this would be appreciated!

Comment: you find this discussed at ncatlab (Theorem 4.1). The site gives a "complete proof": https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Deligne%27s+theorem+on+tensor+categories#TensorCategory